# Create custom AR Quick Look experience without using the device's camera

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, quicklook, usdz

I'm wondering if there's a way to recreate the "Object" experience when viewing a .usdz file through Apple's AR Quick Look. I want an experience that showcases a 3D object without "augmenting reality".

Some options that I'm thinking of that might be able to recreate this feature:
1) Using ARKit, disabling the camera and setting my own background with a custom image. I would then set the usdz/object in the center of the device's screen while having all the interaction functionalityfor the 3D object.

2) Web AR - recreate this 3D experience elsewhere and showcase this on a webview.

Any guidance or discussion about this is much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's [model-viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) if you are going with the web solution. Another easy and effective solution would be [echoAR](https://www.echoar.xyz) (full disclosure, this is where I work). You can simply upload your models there and then get a link to thier model-view. You can upload models in different formats (obj, fbx, glTF, glb, USDZ) and it'll automatically convert it to the format you need to view on any device.